# RabbitMQ - How to separate a RabbitListener to muliple?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

There are many routing keys(200 over), so it is difficult to define in a RabbitListener.

Is it possible to split RabbitListener into multiple parts?

```java
@Controller
@Slf4j
public class EventListener{
    
    @Autowired
    private demoService demoService;
        
    @RabbitListener(queues = "demo.queue")
    public void handleEvent1(@Payload JSONObject jsonObj, @Header(AmqpHeaders.RECEIVED_ROUTING_KEY) String routingKey) {
        
        log.info("handleEvent1==>[{}] : {}", routingKey, jsonObj);
        
        switch(routingKey) {
        case "demo.demo.status": 
            demoService.eventListen(routingKey, jsonObj);
            break;
        case "demo.system.track62":
            demoService.eventListen(routingKey, jsonObj);
            break;
                 ...(200 over)
        }
    }
}
```

I created a Listener in the same way, but if there is no routing key in the switch case statement, the event is lost in result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The routing key in the AMQP protocol allows us to deliver messages to bound by those keys queues: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html.

So, you probably can just bind queues for those routing keys and have respective `@RabbitListener` for each of them. That's the way to separate business logic by routing key. Of course we still can do whatever you have so far, but that looks like an abuse of the feature which was not designed for consumer logic.

Another way is to introduce some strategy which you can resolve by your routing key. For example you can have as many beans of the same type as you have routing key and just get that bean by routing key name from the application context to be called from this your `@RabbitListener`. And so on. I guess there are many ways to implement strategy pattern.

Comment: please be a little more specific. thanks for explaining with the source code.

Comment: Here is a doc how to configure queues in your application: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#builder-api. The strategy for service handlers to use is up to you: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/strategy-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?
I am not sure will it work. just an idea which will helps you.

```java
// Separate to multiple
@RabbitListener(queues = "demo.queue")
public void handleEvent1(@Payload JSONObject jsonObj, @Header(AmqpHeaders.RECEIVED_ROUTING_KEY) String routingKey) {
    
    log.info("handleEvent1==>[{}] : {}", routingKey, jsonObj);
    
    switch(routingKey) {
    case "demo.demo.status": 
    case "demo.system.track62":
        demoService.eventListen(routingKey, jsonObj);
        break;
    }
}

@RabbitListener(queues = "demo.queue")
public void handleEvent2(@Payload JSONObject jsonObj, @Header(AmqpHeaders.RECEIVED_ROUTING_KEY) String routingKey) {
    
    log.info("handleEvent2==>[{}] : {}", routingKey, jsonObj);
    
    switch(routingKey) {
    case "demo.report.miner": 
    case "
```

Comment: I tried it. however, if "demo.demo.status" enters handleEvent2 without entering handleEvent1, the message is lost.

Comment: This won't work; the two listeners become competing consumers on the queue. You cannot have different listeners based on the routing key.